# JQuery-steps Form Validation Plugin not validating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-steps

I am struggling with implementing the form validation for the Jquery-Steps plugin.

I am trying to implement the form validation in it's simplest form at this point, whereas it just validates inputs that have the "required" attribute. When I put a cursor in any box, i get the following error message in my console:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined"

Can someone help a newbie here? I'm totally lost. Thanks.

Here is my form:

```
    <cfform id="form" name="form" method="post" action="actionpages/add_residential_ticket.cfm">
    <cfoutput>
      <input type="hidden" name="ticket_id" id="ticket_id" value="#ticketnum#" readonly>
    </cfoutput>
    <h2>
      <div id="wizard">

          <h2>Your Information</h2>
                <section>
                  <cfinput value="#DateFormat(now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")#" required="yes" type="hidden" name="date" id="date" message="Please enter a date for this service call" tabindex="0" readonly="true"/>     
                      <label for="customer">Your Full Name</label>
                      <input type="text" required  name="customer" id="customer" data-validation="customer" 
         data-validation-error-msg="You did not enter a valid name" >


                      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                      <input type="email" required name="email" id="email">


                      <label for="customer_address">Your Full Mailing Address</label>
                      <textarea required name="customer_address" id="customer_address"></textarea>


                      <label for="phone">Cell Phone Number</label>
                      <input required type="tel" name="phone" id="phone">

                </section>

                <h2>Computer Problem</h2>
                <section>
                      <label for="trouble_reported">Please Provide A Detailed Description Of Your Issue</label><br>
                      <textarea required name="trouble_reported" id="trouble_reported" rows="15" cols="60"></textarea>

                </section>

                <h2>Your Equipment</h2>
                <section>
                    <label for="equipment">What Equipment Are You Leaving With Us?</label><br>
                      <textarea required name="equipment" id="equipment"></textarea>
                      <br>

                      <label for="customerPWD">Do You Have A Password?</label>
                      <input required type="text" autocapitalize="none" name="customerPWD" id="customerPWD">
                      <br>
                </section>

                <h2>How Did You Find Us</h2>
                <section>
                    <label for="hdyfu">Please let us know how you found us</label>
                      <cfselect required queryPosition="below" query="hdyfu" display="method" name="hdyfu" id="hdyfu" tabindex="0" ><option>---Make A Selection---</option></cfselect>
                      <br>

                </section>
            </div>

<!--- Mobile Sig Capture CSS --->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/signature-pad.css">

    </h2>

  </cfform>
```

Here is my Jquery-steps Javascript:

```
<!--- JQUERY-Steps --->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.steps.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/jquery.steps.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!--- JQUERY Validator --->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

     <!--- Initialize the JQUERY-Steps plugin --->
<script>
$(function ()
{
$("#wizard").steps({
    headerTag: "h2",
    bodyTag: "section",
    saveState: true,
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",

        onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
             $("#form1").validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
             return $("#form").valid();
        },
        onFinishing: function(event, currentIndex) {
            $("#form1").validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
            return $("#form").valid();
        },
        onFinished: function(event, currentIndex) {
            alert("Submitted!");
        }
    }).validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            element.before(error);
        },
        rules: {
            confirm: {
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        }
    });     
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upwork got me here :D.As far as i can see in your code,you are not including jQuery anywhere in your code,and it is required - that can be your error.Other thing is that you are using required as an attribute and it should be in a class like this class="required".